# Wanted: Android versions of JDBC drivers for common RDMBSes

Tags: jdbc

I've got a Java-based application library I'm trying to port to Android. The package presently supports:

- Oracle
- Informix
- DB2
- Postgres
- Sybase

...And can easily be configured to use any other SQL92 compliant RDBMS that has a JDBC driver. It would be nice to keep this flexibility.

However, I've been having troubles converting over the JDBC drivers. [I've asked about this on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891846/java-dx-utility-unexpected-top-level-error-java-lang-exceptionininitializererro), but no solution yet.

Meanwhile, I'm wondering if anyone has successfully converted any of these JDBC driver packages and has made them available via the internet. There should be no license issues with at least any of these packages since all these are are access libraries and not the DBMS itself - all these vendors give away the JDBC drivers! But I've been looking and haven't found anything.

Anyone?